# Change name of storyboard reference

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I've been refactoring a giant storyboard into smaller ones.  For the first few I did, i didn't set friendly names for the storyboard ID's. therefore some of the segues are pointing to storyboard references with the internal name (such as `UITableViewController-pF0-sDc-w0D`).  I've since added friendly names but these references haven't been updated and are therefore confusing.  Is there a safe way to change this name without breaking the reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can manual change the reference name by edit the Storyboard code directly without recreate the connections.

First rename your code to new name in ViewController by Refactor or manual

```
   @IBOutlet weak var skView: SKView!
```

Say you wish to change the name to

```
   @IBOutlet weak var goodskView: SKView!
```

Then open the storyboard by "Right Click" Open As > Source Code, use find function to search the original name

```
<connections>
                        <outlet property="skView" destination="HLz-n2-wPe" id="lq0-bU-XZj"/>
                        <outlet property="toolbar" destination="TNu-gh-H4d" id="3Wb-7n-KOM"/>
                    </connections>
```

Change the property name to the new one. Confirm the mother node is correct , as Storyboard "property" can be some name in other hierarchy.

```
<connections>
                        <outlet property="goodskView" destination="HLz-n2-wPe" id="lq0-bU-XZj"/>
                        <outlet property="toolbar" destination="TNu-gh-H4d" id="3Wb-7n-KOM"/>
                    </connections>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to introduce more readability to your code but you are afraid of changing the identifiers in the storyboards. You can trick it a little bit.

Introduce an enum with the type of string which will contain all the nice names for all your storyboard segues identifiers.

```
enum Segues: String
{
    case DisplaySomeScreen = "Very-Long-And-Vague-Name-123"
    case DisplayOtherScreen = "Very-Long-And-Vague-Name-455"
}
```

Next, you can execute the segue in the following way.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: Segues.DisplayOtherScreen.rawValue, sender: self)
```

By using this approach, you can introduce the nice descriptive names of your segues and at the same time, you can defer changing the actual names to the moment in which you will be convenient about doing so. You can do the same for the storyboard identifiers of your view controllers.